# How to get the selected checkbox value from the row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to get the selected the check box row text values from the row.I'm using jstl tags to display the list of records in page.Please see my code below...

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="product">
<td><input type="text" value='${product.featurename}' name="featurename" readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td><input type="text" value='${product.featureversion}' readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td><input type="text" value='${product.end_date}' readonly="readonly"/></td>
<td><input type="text" value='${product.new_end_date}' class="datepicker" /></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" value='${product.new_end_date}' name="new_end_date" class="selectedId"/>
</c:forEach>
```

java class :

```
String[] newenddate = req.getParameterValues("new_end_date");
```

Jquery for selectAll

```
$('#selectall').click(function(i, v){
        $('.selectedId').prop('checked', this.checked);
    });

    var checkCount = $('.selectedId').length;
    $('.selectedId').click(function(i, v){
        $('#selectall').prop('checked',$('.selectedId:checked').length  == checkCount);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.selectedId:checked').each(function(index, value) {
    // gets row inputs
    var $inputs = $(this).closest('tr').find('input[type="text"]');

    // do something here
});
```

You can change the find's selector as you need.

By the way, you missed a `</td>` on the last column cell.